# Unique lines based on the first field

Tags: shell, osx, uniq

How can you find unique lines or duplicate lines in a file based on the content of the first field, or the first n characters ?

The uniq command on OS X lacks the `-w` switch that is available under Linux: `-w, --check-chars=N : compare no more than N characters in lines`, which solves the problem.

Can it be done without reimplementing `uniq` in awk ?

The number of fields is not constant. I would like to use only default tools installed on OS X. I use Macports a lot, but in this case, I don't want to use them.

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915636/is-there-a-way-to-uniq-by-column

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using `sort -u`?  This can at least sort by the first field:

```
 sort -k 1,1 -u input_file
```

Comment: I used this, and defered the treatement of unique or duplicate lines a bit later with a: `while read firstField otherFields; do stuffs..`